# Create an empty object/array, based on an existing object/array

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a function that takes as an argument either an object or an array, and I want to create a new, empty copy of it and populate it with transformed data from the original object.

I'm wondering if there's a way to make this new object/array simply, without having to test what type the thing is and act appropriately.

The 'long' way is currently to do:

```
const transf = (thing) => {
  if (typeof(thing) === 'array') {
    const new = []
  }  else {
    const new = {}
  }
}
```

I'm hoping there's a nice 'builtin' way I can do something like:

```
const transf = (thing) => {
  const new = thing.emptyCopy()
}
```

I've looked at `Object.create` but that always makes an `object` (even if the `prototype` is an `array`), and `typeof` returns a string, which can't be used with e.g. `new` etc.

Is there a shorthand way to do this, or am I out of luck?

Comment: use `constructor` method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `constructor` property of `thing`. And don't use `new` as variable name.

```
const transf = (thing) => {
  const newelm = new thing.constructor()
}
```

Demo:

```js
const transf = (thing) => {
  return new thing.constructor()
}

console.log(transf(['arra']))
console.log(transf({key:'value'}))
```

Comment: @raina77ow Yeah, although if only `Object` and `Array` are considered it doesn't matter

Comment: Thanks - yes - not sure why I used `new` there!

Comment: @match Consider accepting the answer if you are satisfied with it.